# Outputting different class other than default for status messages

Tags: 7, theming, status-messages

I'm trying to theme status messages, I want to change the HTML of the message.

Drupal default is

```
 <div class="message status">message!</div>
```

What I want to achieve is

```
 <div class="alert alert-success">message!</div>
```

I have used theme_status_messages to modify 'messages' but how can I modify the type (e.g. 'status'/'warning', etc)?

This is current code

```
function theme_status_messages($variables) {
  $display = $variables['display'];
  $output = '';

  $status_heading = array(
    'status' => t('Status message'),
    'error' => t('Error message'),
    'warning' => t('Warning message'),
  );
  foreach (drupal_get_messages($display) as $type => $messages) {
    $output .= "<div class=\"alert $type\">\n";
    if (!empty($status_heading[$type])) {
      $output .= '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . $status_heading[$type] . "</h2>\n";
    }
    if (count($messages) > 1) {
      $output .= " <ul>\n";
      foreach ($messages as $message) {
        $output .= '  <li>' . $message . "</li>\n";
      }
      $output .= " </ul>\n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= $messages[0];
    }
    $output .= "</div>\n";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

I've changed this line

```
$output .= "<div class=\"messages $type\">\n";
```

to

```
$output .= "<div class=\"alert $type\">\n";
```

as you can see in my code above, but how can I change the options for $type?? I want my types to be alert-success, alert-error, alert-warning, rather than status, error, warning.

Anyone got an idea?

thanks!

Comment: I have no clue what you're asking for.

Comment: @caustic Why not just switch your CSS classes to correspond with the default Drupal ones?

Comment: Can't just do: `$output .= "<div class=\"messages alert-$type\">\n";` ?

Comment: @slawrence10 I'm using Bootstrap and requirements are that theres no additional classes for Bootstrap-served elements. Bootstrap has it alert alert-success format

Comment: @Beebee I caaaaan, but that still doesn't work. Because $type isn't correct. alert-$type will give me alert-status rather than alert-success. Any ideas?

Comment: @Beebee what I'm asking for is a way to change the default 3 message type classes - status, error, and warning. I want to change them to alert-succes, alert-info, alert-danger, for example.

Comment: That's so easy, you're just changing output. Check my answer.

Comment: I had to edit your original question in order to retract my downvote. Hopefully it made the question easier to understand too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just some good old PHP logic, is this what you're after?

```
function theme_status_messages($variables) {
  $display = $variables['display'];
  $output = '';

  $status_heading = array(
    'status' => t('Status message'),
    'error' => t('Error message'),
    'warning' => t('Warning message'),
  );

  // Map our drupal statuses to bootstrap classes
  $bootstrap_statuses = array(
    'status' => 'alert-success',
    'error' => 'alert-error',
    'warning' => 'alert-warning',
  );

  foreach (drupal_get_messages($display) as $type => $messages) {
    // Grab the bootstrap class that corresponds to $type
    $bootstrap_class = $bootstrap_statuses[$type];
    $output .= "<div class=\"alert $bootstrap_class\">\n";
    if (!empty($status_heading[$type])) {
      $output .= '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . $status_heading[$type] . "</h2>\n";
    }
    if (count($messages) > 1) {
      $output .= " <ul>\n";
      foreach ($messages as $message) {
        $output .= '  <li>' . $message . "</li>\n";
      }
      $output .= " </ul>\n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= $messages[0];
    }
    $output .= "</div>\n";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

You could even put the `$bootstrap_classes` and `$status_heading` arrays together. But I separated them for simplicity

Comment: Thank you very much , didn't realise it was so simple, thought that maybe there was another hook for that :) Works anyway!

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it's worth to take a step back and think "Can I solve this with good ol' PHP?" :) I've been there so many times.